# Multi-layer SankeyNetwork (NetworkD3) does not plot in R

Tags: r, d3.js, dplyr, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I have been successfully using the NetworkD3 package to plot 2-layer Sankey Networks. I created a function which takes a dataframe of columns source, target, and value and outputs a Sankey plot. I use this function to help quickly produce similar plots. My question isn't about the efficiency of the function - though perhaps the source of my problem is in it.

Below I provide a reproducible example. I demonstrate how my function produces a SankeyNetwork for two datasets - z1 & z2. However, when I combine these datasets with the idea of creating a 3-layer SankeyNetwork - nothing plots in the viewer (and I have tried to increase width and height as well). I'm guessing this might have something to do with indexing, though in the past I would get an error output about needing to zero-index. I receive no errors, just a blank plot.

```
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr)


# The function used to create the plots
sanktify <- function(x) {

  # Create nodes DF with the unique sources & targets from input
  nodes <- unique(data.frame(c(unique(x$source), unique(x$target))))
  nodes$ID <- as.numeric(rownames(nodes)) - 1 # sankeyNetwork requires IDs to be zero-indexed
  names(nodes) <- c("name", "ID")

  # Create two versions of nodes for merging
  nodes_source <- nodes
  nodes_target <- nodes

  names(nodes_source) <- c("source", "source_ID")
  names(nodes_target) <- c("target", "target_ID")

  # Replace source & target in links DF with IDs
  links <- merge(x, nodes_source, by="source", all.x=TRUE) %>%
    merge(nodes_target, by="target", all.x=TRUE) %>%
    select(source_ID, target_ID, value) %>%
    arrange(source_ID)

  # Create Sankey Plot
  sank <- sankeyNetwork(
    Links = links,
    Nodes = nodes,
    Source = "source_ID",
    Target = "target_ID",
    Value = "value",
    NodeID = "name",
    units = "USD",
    fontSize = 12,
    nodeWidth = 30
  )

  return(sank)

}


# Creating & plotting first data frame.
z1 <- tbl_df(data.frame(source = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                        target = c("Cardiovascular", "Neurological", "Cardiovascular", "Neurological"),
                        value = c(5, 8, 2, 10)))

z1$source <- as.character(z1$source)
z1$target <- as.character(z1$target)
sanktify(z1) # Correctly produces plot


# Creating & plotting 2nd data frame
z2 <- tbl_df(data.frame( source = c("Cardiovascular", "Cardiovascular", "Neurological", "Neurological"),
                         target = c("IP Surg", "IP Med", "IP Surg", "IP Med"),
                         value = c(3, 7, 6, 1)))

z2$source <- as.character(z2$source)
z2$target <- as.character(z2$target)
sanktify(z2) # Correctly produces plot

# Combining the two dataframes into a new DF with the goal of creating a '3-layer' plot.
z3 <- rbind(z1, z2)
sanktify(z3) # Blank output. No errors in the R console
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer should be in the cross-posted Github issue https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/issues/134.  I will copy and paste the code here also.  `unique` is in the wrong place and needs to run after the concatenate of source and target.

```
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr)


# The function used to create the plots
sanktify <- function(x) {

  # Create nodes DF with the unique sources & targets from input

  #  ***** changing this is the key***********************************************************
  nodes <- data.frame(unique(c(x$source,x$target)),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  # ************************************************************************************************
  nodes$ID <- as.numeric(rownames(nodes)) - 1 # sankeyNetwork requires IDs to be zero-indexed
  names(nodes) <- c("name", "ID")

  # use dplyr join over merge since much better; in this case not big enough to matter
  # Replace source & target in links DF with IDs
  links <- inner_join(x, nodes, by = c("source"="name")) %>%
    rename(source_ID = ID) %>%
    inner_join(nodes, by = c("target"="name")) %>%
    rename(target_ID = ID) 

  # Create Sankey Plot
  sank <- sankeyNetwork(
    Links = links,
    Nodes = nodes,
    Source = "source_ID",
    Target = "target_ID",
    Value = "value",
    NodeID = "name",
    units = "USD",
    fontSize = 12,
    nodeWidth = 30
  )

  return(sank)

}



# use data_frame to avoid tbl_df(data.frame(
z1 <- data_frame(
  source = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  target = c("Cardiovascular", "Neurological", "Cardiovascular", "Neurological"),
  value = c(5, 8, 2, 10)
)
z2 <- data_frame(
  source = c("Cardiovascular", "Cardiovascular", "Neurological", "Neurological"),
  target = c("IP Surg", "IP Med", "IP Surg", "IP Med"),
  value = c(3, 7, 6, 1)
)

z3 <- bind_rows(z1,z2)
sanktify(z3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite doing a lot of tedious step-by-step work to root out the problem, I embarrassingly never tried to reverse the order in which I rbind the two dataframes together.

z3 <- rbind(z2,z1) works with the Sanktify function while z3 <- rbind(z1,z2) produces a blank plot.

Not sure why - as my function is designed to provide a zero-indexed ID #. So if anyone with a better understanding of JS/D3 knows, I'm curious.